# Change background color of a row on the fly when checkbox is selected by default

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-events

I have a table that is generated on the fly with php. I need to change the color of an entire row of the table if the last checkbox is checked (in the column named "OK").  I found this code from other post here and works fine, except that the color toggle is working only when you click on it, and not when is checked by default.

I understand that the problem is that the javascript code is calling the function "on checkbox change" and nothing changes when the page is loaded. However I have not idea how to modify the script to make it work also when the page loads :(

```js
$('input[name="chkOrgRow"]').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('yellow', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

```css
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> C1 </td>
    <td> C2</td>
    <td> C3 </td>
    <td> C4 </td>
    <td> OK </td>
    <td> &nbsp; </td>
  
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><input type='checkbox' name='whatever' /></td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='chkOrgRow' /></td> 
    <td> &nbsp; </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
     <td><input type='checkbox' name='whatever' /></td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='chkOrgRow' checked="checked" /></td> 
    <td><--- This must be highlighted because the OK checkbox is enabled</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
     <td><input type='checkbox' name='whatever' /></td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='chkOrgRow' /></td> 
    <td> &nbsp; </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get jQuery to run the function [on page load](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="chkOrgRow"]:checked').closest('tr').addClass('yellow');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/88oq246w/2/

Comment: Yes, though I think I accidentally pasted `this` from your original. See updated answer.

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using `.closest()` and `.next()` jquery functions.

```
$('input[name="chkOrgRow"]').on('change', function() {
  $(this)
  .closest('td') // find the closest td ( parent of input ) , you can also use .parent() for this
  .next('td') // find the next occuring td element
  .toggleClass('yellow', $(this).is(':checked')); // toggles the class 'Yellow' if checked
});
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/r6okrvm1/

UPDATE : To set class `'Yellow'` on page load for `inputs` which are selected

```
$().ready(function(){
$('input[name="chkOrgRow"]:checked').closest('td').next('td').toggleClass('yellow');
  });
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/r6okrvm1/1/

Comment: Thank you, but the code was working OK before, I just want the row to be highlighted also when page load if the checkbox is enabled before pressing any ckeckbox